# How to Prepopulate Account field of opportunity with the name of Account

Tags: lightning-aura-components

My requirement is to develop a button in Account object to create Opportunity.There by Account field of Opportunity should be get prepopulated by the Account name in which Opportunity is being created.This all to be done using Lightning components.Can anyone suggest the best approach?

Comment: Have you started developing something? Its not clear exactly what you are asking for and your question might be closed as too broad. Please take a moment to read [ask] and rake the [tour] in order to get familiar with the forum, thanks!